# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement when adding new script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firebug

I get the following error in Firebug for my JavaScript application:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement when adding new script
```

The error relates to Google Analytics, but I only get the error when I add another script using `RegisterStartupScript`. I've had same error point to the script below whilst testing too, so I think the Google thing is a red herring.

Here is the script that gets rendered:

```
<script src="https://www.thedomain.com/pixel/confirmationjs?pthru=1055|1|pixeltest|27902471&dlp=1.20">
</script>
```

How do I solve this problem in ASP.NET with `RegisterStartupScript`?

Answer (score 0):

When getting your technical info of a salesman, never accept what he says to be the complete story or the whole truth!
Turns out that the pixel image I was testing against was single use only, so it worked first time and gave an error on subsequent calls.